# How to change name of "My Project" in Solution Explorer Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

When I'm creating a new project there's also a folder created by default named "My Project" I searched but didn't find a proper answer for that. Answers are usually related to changing name of project. There's no problem with my project name my problem is default created folder named "My Project" with wrench icon near it. I'm using Visual Studio 2013. When i'm right click to rename it there are only options like:

> Open
>
> Scope to this

I'll be glad if anybody knows the solution.

Comment: Right click.  Select `Rename`

Comment: @Plutonix there's no option like rename. There's wrench icon near this.

Comment: Right click on the actual solution name.  https://i.imgur.com/pE5LBRs.jpg  It is probablynear the bottom

Comment: Could you explain why you need to rename it?  I'm not sure there is a way to do that--I've never tried and I've never heard of anyone else ever doing it.  It's a rather unusual thing, since it's a standard folder for all VB projects which everyone expects to be there.

Comment: If it was possible to do, I'd assume that it would involve manually editing the `vbproj` file.  But even if it compiled successfully after that, I wouldn't be shocked if it broke the project properties designer.

Comment: @StevenDoggart thanks for your reply. I only wonder if it is changable property i would like to rename it lower case without any space character in naming. So i tried to rename. But if you say it's default, ok i'll keep like that.